# Website translation onload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, smarty

I have a dating site which is currently in English language.
As per client requirement he told me to convert the website in Polish language.
If I will create language file for the website, then I need to rework on whole project.
Is there any technique so that my website is automatically translated into Polish language when it is loading in browser. There also some hidden div's that will be displayed when a specific event occurs.

The website is created in php with smarty templating.

Please help me for this.

Thanks

Comment: Store all texts in a database and add a new field for the new language. Or look into [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) functionality.

Comment: Dear I have already said I don't want to rework on this.

Comment: If you don't want to do it right, then just use [google auto translate](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173424) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a custom solution, you're going to have to do some editing of your current code.

**Option 1**

Store all your strings in [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) files or within a database, or flat file, or however else you want them stored. The fact of the matter is that, as soon as your application loads, it'll query the database for the strings in your language (your url will have /en, /fr, /de etc at the end) and place those onto your page.

This means you'll have to code the retrieval of this data, and placement within your application.

**Option 2**

Use Google's "[Auto Translate](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173424)" as per Dainis' suggestion in the comments. This isn't as customisable, but means you don't have to do any reworking of your current code.

**Option 3**

Use [Bing's translate API](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis) and manually request strings for the data you want translated on each request. Access to the Bing API is free for developers and has loads of free translations included - but this will be data intensive unless you *cache the translations* for future use.

With Option 3, you'll still have to code your own custom solution. So if you're on a tight deadline or you're just plain lazy, go with Option 2.

Comment: Nice find! I'll add it as Option 4 and, if you think this post was useful, would you up-vote and tick as correct?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have applied [translateThis](http://translateth.is/) into website. It translates only displayed data not the hidden data which shows after a specific event occurs like user click on a button etc. And it translated the data when user click on the link not automatically so in that case user first get data in English. Is google translate the data automatically. So that Your will never see data in English rather data is always displayed in Polish language.

Comment: @surinder This was your research, so if it's not an effective solution then why did you comment that it was? Don't forget everything posted here is likely to be useful for other people with the same question.

Comment: Dear @Jimbo I will keep it my mind whenever I post a question. Thanks